# Identify if someone has paid in an excel spreadsheet and create text to say they have

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm a sports club treasurer, god knows why.

Each month I download the monthly statement from the bank and then have to check by hand to see that each member has paid their monthly due.

Is there a way I can create a formula for each user that would search Column B for the name 'John Smith' and if it's present, under Column C, create the text 'John Smith has paid' or something?

I've tried playing with the find and search functions but no joy so far.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I've just tried using:

=IF(B1:B500 = "HEGARTY", "Not paid", "Paid")

But that doesn't work. I'd based it on the >0 version I'd seen. It just keeps saying 'Paid' so the formula isn't working.

Comment: Give more info about the structure of the files/spreadsheet and what/where should be done. Some examples would be good.

Comment: As it currently stands: 

`A1 is transaction date. 
B1 is payee account details - it's all in one line. Name, account number, sort code, time. 
C1 is Debit, 
D1 is Credit
E1 is total balance.`

I'm looking to pull a name from B1 - so an example Payee is:

**JOHN SMITH SMITH 0344553699632BBBKLYN 090128     10 16JUN18 20:06**

From that, I'd want the formula to search all of B and find 'JOHN SMITH' and put 'John Smith has paid' in an end column. That way I can scan the list, and tick them off on my account book. Hope that helps?

Comment: I'm trying VLOOKUP but it just returns #N/A with the following:

`=VLOOKUP("KOKES",A2:A500,A1:A500,FALSE)`

Comment: Any lookup function (VLOOKUP, MATCH, etc.) compares against the entire cell content, they don't act like a "contains" function.  There is also the question of identifying each name anywhere in the data.  Please expand the question to show all of the relevant parts (mock-up of bank data, mock-up of member data, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using a combination of `IF()` and `COUNTIF()`:

[image: Example]

For the sake of this question the values in A, C, D and E are not important, however it does assume that your `NAME` is identical to that which you receive from the bank.

The formula is:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B:B,"*"&J2&"*")>0,"PAID","NOT PAID")
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Fixed bug in formula

---

Here's a solution using the standard `INDEX(…,MATCH())` technique:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in `I3` and ctrl-enter/copy-paste/fill-down the column:

```dart
=IF(IFERROR(INDEX(D:D,MATCH(H3&"*",B:B,0)),0)>0,"Paid","Not paid")
```

If this formula finds a transaction that matches the member, it checks to see if the `Credit` column contains a value to determine if the due has been paid.  This could easily be adapted to determine if the full amount has been paid or only a part payment has been received.

**Explanation:**

If the third argument of `MATCH()` is a `0` (exact match), then the find string can use wildcards. `*` means zero or more characters, so `MATCH("JOHN SMITH SMITH*",…,0)` means match the first string starting with the phrase `JOHN SMITH SMITH`.