# Return and sum multiple values using a wildcard criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I'm trying to create a complex formula that does the following:

1. Looks up data in column `A` of another sheet using a "contains" criteria (`xxxx&"*"`)
2. Returns **all** matching values from a specific column (column `B`)
3. Sums the returned values to provide a total

I've attached a view of some sample data as an example of the data-set I'm working with:

[image: sample data]

For instance, I may want to show the total number of apples, regardless of their colour (`8`), in a single cell.

I've tried a number of things (`VLOOKUP`, `INDEX`, `MATCH`) but I can't seem to get it 100% right.

Comment: See this previous question for examples of how to use wildcards: https://superuser.com/questions/1333733/identify-if-someone-has-paid-in-an-excel-spreadsheet-and-create-text-to-say-they

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is very simple. You need to use the `SUMIF()` function.

With two worksheets set up like this:

[image: Worksheet Screenshot]  [image: Worksheet Screenshot]

Enter the following formula in cell `B2` of `Sheet1`:

```dart
=SUMIF(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,A2&"*",Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5)
```

Note that this formula actually performs a "starts with".

The "contains" formula needs another wildcard:

```dart
=SUMIF(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,"*"&A2&"*",Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5)
```

---

**Wildcards Explanation**

There are three wildcard characters that can be used in some Excel functions:

- `?` - matches any **one** character
- `*` - matches **zero or more** characters
- `~` - "escapes" the following character, e.g. `~?`,`~*`, and `~~` will match the literal characters `?`,`*`,and `~` respectively. Note that `~` followed by any other character will *only* match that character, **not** a tilde followed by that character

The most useful functions allowing the usage of wildcards are:

- `SEARCH()`
- `MATCH()`<sup>*</sup>
- `VLOOKUP()` & `HLOOKUP`<sup>*</sup>
- `SUMIF()`, `SUMIFS()`, `COUNTIF()`, `COUNTIFS()`, `AVERAGEIF()` & `AVERAGEIFS()`

<sup>*</sup> Wildcards can only be used if the third argument of `MATCH()` is a `0` (exact match) or the fourth argument of `VLOOKUP()`/`HLOOKUP()` is `TRUE` (exact match)